# DNS/Nameserver problems & ISPConfig

Tags: domain-name-system

My domain rscharts.com is suppose to connect to my VPS server, and the server is 212.1.209.246.

However, the domain rscharts.com simply won't work. I'm new to all of this; my first time having a VPS.

```
Searching for rscharts.com. A record at M.ROOT-SERVERS.NET. [202.12.27.33] ...took 10 ms
Searching for rscharts.com. A record at d.gtld-servers.net. [192.31.80.30] ...took 116 ms
Searching for rscharts.com. A record at ns1.rscharts.com. [212.1.209.246] null
Searching for rscharts.com. A record at ns2.rscharts.com. [212.1.209.246] null
Searching for rscharts.com. A record at ns1.rscharts.com. [212.1.209.246] null
Searching for rscharts.com. A record at ns2.rscharts.com. [212.1.209.246] null
None of the nameservers responded correctly.
```

I'm not sure why it doesn't work **(am I missing a record, do I have any records configured wrong?)**, as I've set up everything I needed in ISPConfig's DNS zone:

http://puu.sh/4wPlQ.png

http://puu.sh/4wPjG.png

puu.sh/4wPkz.png

Can anyone please help me with this? My website has been down for an entire week.

Comment: Who hosts and manages ns1.rscharts.com and ns2.rscharts.com? Is the rscharts.com zone set up and configured on those two servers?

Comment: My host manages ns1.rscharts.com and ns2.rscharts.com - they have assured me that the problem is not on their part, and that the problem is due to the server being "misconfigured." And I'm on an "unmanaged" server, so I cannot get any help regarding the issue.

Comment: Curiously, those two nameservers, which share the same IP and are really the same server apparently (Bad!  Don't do that!!) resolve IN A rscharts.com. just fine (and resolve it to the same IP they share, curiously).  So either your host is lying and has misconfigured them, or you control them and they are working fine.

Comment: Where does that diagnostic output you included in the question come from?  Both name servers work for me and the hierarchy down to them is working correctly.  I suspect the tool is broken.  The website itself is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

looks like you are not running bind on that IP:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.7.6-P1 <<>> @212.1.209.246 rscharts.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

check to make sure bind is running and listening on not just localhost, and that you dont have udp/53 closed by iptables.  also make sure that ip is actually what is assigned to your VPS.

Comment: I believe my host should already have binded my domain to the server.

Comment: let me clarify .... udp/53 is *not* open on 212.1.209.246  ... until that changes, your domain will not resolve on the internet